# How can I programmatically prevent an app from going to the background when the user takes off the Apple Vision Pro?

Tags: visionos, vision-pro

I'm developing a vision pro application.
However, when the user takes off the Apple Vision Pro device, the application goes into the background.
How can I prevent this behavior programmatically?

I haven't tried anything yet.
I was hoping to receive some guidance on how to prevent my application from going to the background when the Apple Vision Pro device is removed.